# Using composer without dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php

I have project with this scheme:

- main project depends on subprojects

  - subproject 1 with some own dependencies
  - subproject 2 with some own dependencies
  - subproject 3 with some own dependencies

I'm curious if I can use composer to do job. I would like that packages (subprojects) with [type "project"](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#type) behave like standalone project, not like library.

I found workaround, if in main project composer.json [provide/replace](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links) all dependencies from subprojects, I can use composer install/update and don't bother about conflicts. I can use custom [installer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md) to put subprojects in proper directories and [plugin](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md) or [script](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) to install dependencies for every subproject. This works but is quite hard to maintain, if any subproject adds dependency I need to modify main project composer.json.

Is way to use composer for this task or I should abandon idea write simple tool? What do you think?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a very good structure... Libraries shouldn't depend on the location of the vendors, they should just depend on the existence of vendor classes. (it's composer's task to make them available and know where they live)

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe it clear enough, I would like to manage dependencies between applications (subprojects) included in bigger system (main project). Of course composer manage libraries' dependencies inside monolite application but I'm curious if I can use it on higher level manage standalone applications instead of libraries.